# How to intersect two comma separated string in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I want to intersect two comma separated string from two columns of mysql table:

My query is as follows:

```
select ucg.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(seek_mentorship_in),  ',','100000') as skill_seeker_list
from user_career_goals as ucg
where SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(seek_mentorship_in), ',','100000') IN  (select GROUP_CONCAT(provide_mentorship_in) from user_career_goals)
and user_id=784;
```

**1.** For user_id is 784
**2.** I want the list of all user_ids from the same table where seek_mentorship_in comma separated string intersect with all provide_mentorship_in comma separated string.

[image]

Comment: Redesign your database to use proper relational tables that do *not* store multiple values in a single column.